# Is there a more efficient way to get email suffix than explode? (PHP)

Tags: php, email

Current Code I'm using to get email suffix

```
$emailarray  = explode('@',$email_address);
$emailSuffix = $emailarray[1];
```

There's gotta be a more efficient function.  Maybe something using `substr()`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient' and why do you ask? I don't see how anything can be more efficient than that.

Comment: Unless you're doing this a few million times in a row, the minor overhead of explode having to create a new array is going to be absolutely miniuscule.

Comment: you can shorten your example down to a single line with: list($user,$domain)=explode('@',$email_address);

Comment: Wasn't sure about memory overhead.

Comment: Whatever it's worth, an @ is a legal character to have in the "name" portion of an email address as in Abc\@def@example.com
 see: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#section-3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shorter:

```
$emailSuffix = end(explode('@', $email_address));
```

But I don't think it gets any significantly more efficient than that. Regex is probably slower.

### EDIT

I did some testing and although this version was 3 times faster than using the

```
$a = explode('@', $email_address);
$foo = $a[1];
```

and

```
if (preg_match('~^.+@(.+)$~', $email_address, $reg))
  $foo = $reg[1];
```

it doesn't comply with the **strict** standards:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

### EDIT2

```
$foo = substr($email_address, strpos($email_address, '@'));
```

is about as fast as the end(explode(.)) method so I would suggest that one. Please see rayman86's answer and comments.

Answer (score 3):

Using regex, and the [**`preg_match`**](http://fr.php.net/preg_match) function, you could have something like this :

```
$email_address = 'hello@world.com';
if (preg_match('/@(.*)$/', $email_address, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Not sure if it's more efficient *(it takes more than a single line of code ; and is probably not faster than your solution)* -- but it should work quite well.

Comment: the PCRE functions are slower than their str counterparts.  Should matter very little here, but substr/strpos should be faster .. explode would probably be about the same speed though.

Answer (score 2):

```
$emailSuffix = substr($email_address, strpos($email_address, '@'));
```

Comment: `strpos` should work just as well as `strrpos`, as email addresses aren't really allowed to contain multiple `@`

Comment: Yeah I meant for `strpos`, the r key got a little happy - fixed ty

Comment: Well, depends on the emails you use - one could make an analysis of the database of what is longer in average - the user part or the domain part.

Comment: @Czechnology: I personally assumed that the domain would be the longer part on average.  I'm not sure of that, though.

Comment: That's really up for analysis of the database. If most of the emails are the big mail servers like gmail or hotmail, strrpos is probably faster.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is

```
$emailSuffix = substr(strstr($email_address, '@'), 1);
```

Sadly, [`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr) and [`strrchr`](http://php.net/strrchr) have no "exclude needle" setting, so the substring is required.

Answer (score 0):

[Preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match)?